# AS3/Flash: XML to array

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, flash, autocomplete, components

How may I populate an array formated like this?:

```
var names:Array = [{label:"JAMES"}, {label:"JANE"}, {label:"JAMEL"}...];
```

From a XML like this one?:

```
<a>
  <ap>
     <name>JAMES</name>
     <age>36</age>
  </ap>
</a>
```

This is for AutoComplete components.

**UPDATE, to start with something more suitable to my skills. THIS:**

```
<list>
  <label>ALPHA</label>
  <label>ALLAN</label>
  <label>ANTARES</label>
  <label>...</label>
</list>
```

TO THIS:

```
var list:Array = [{label:"ALPHA"}, {label:"ALLAN"}, {label:"ANTARES"}...];
```

Comment: http://krasimirtsonev.com/blog/article/as3-action-script-convert-xml-to-json-xml2json

Comment: Use native XML.toJSON() method. But for what? http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/JSON.html

Comment: krasimirtsonev.com/blog/article/ <-- Call to a possibly undefined method parse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const xml:XML =
    <list>
        <label>ALPHA</label>
        <label>ALLAN</label>
        <label>ANTARES</label>
        <label>...</label>
    </list>;

const list:Array = new Array();

//xml..label.(trace(text()));
xml..label.(list.push({label:text()}));

// now we have an array:
// [{label:"ALPHA"}, {label:"ALLAN"}, {label:"ANTARES"}, {label:"..."}]
```

I recommend to read the AVM2 specification and to pay special attention to namespaces. Seriously. It's interesting and it's fun!

---

Hmmm... Alternative boring way:

```
const list:Array = new Array();
const xml:XML =
    <list>
        <label>ALPHA</label>
        <label>ALLAN</label>
        <label>ANTARES</label>
        <label>...</label>
    </list>;

const labels:XMLList = xml..label;
for each(var node:XML in labels)
{
    trace(node);
    var arrayItem:Object = new Object();
    arrayItem.label = node.text(); // or node.toString() or .toJSON() or .to...
    arrayItem.name = node.name();

    // added only for debug-trace:
    arrayItem.toString = function():String
    {
        var result:String = '{', delimiter:String = '';
        for(var key:String in this)
            if(key !== 'toString')
                result += delimiter + key + ':"' + this[key] + '"',
                    delimiter ||= ', ';
        return result + '}';
    }

    // add item to list:
    list.push(arrayItem);
}

trace(list);
```

Comment: Thanks A.K. for your time. I'm still a bit confused with the levels. I did update the question to make it more suitable to my skills.

Comment: Many, many thanks A.K.! You are very kind. I'll read the AVM2 spec.

Comment: Thank you. 15 years with Flash.

Comment: Hi again A.K. I did test the list array as a data provider and it works like a charm, but how do I trace the whole list? I'm getting [object Object],[object Object],...

Comment: I mean, to trace the whole generated array as string: [{label:"ALPHA"}, {label:"ALLAN"}, {label:"ANTARES"}, {label:"..."}]